# Neovim error on PlugInstall <SNR>3_job_handler

Tags: vim, neovim

Getting following error on Running 
:PlugInstall

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>3_job_handler:
E121: Undefined variable: self
```

The plugin installation never completes.

Part of my .vimrc

```
set nocompatible        
set hidden
set nowrap
set termguicolors
filetype on
map  <c-l> :tabn<cr>
map  <c-h> :tabp<cr>
map  <c-n> :tabnew<cr>
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

....

"typescript
Plug 'mhartington/nvim-typescript'
call plug#end()
```

Comment: What plugin are you using for plugin management? Is it Vundle? Can you share plugin part of vimrc?

Comment: I am using vim-plug

Comment: I started getting this error when i tried to install nvim-typescript. Previously it was running fine @sudobangbang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to update the vim-plug

I ran

```
curl -fLo ~/.local/share/nvim/site/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

It works fine now

Comment: if you've it already installed (e.g. from AUR, etc.) you can do `:PlugUpgrade`

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed, but for some reason vim-plug hasn't released [for 2 years](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/releases) as of writing this. If this is still true when you are reading this, make sure you are using the git master branch, not the latest release. If you are using a package manager you most likely have the outdated one.

If you're instaiing form AUR, use `neovim-plug-git`, not `neovim-plug`. :PlugUpgrade should work as well, but the issue is more likely to resurface that way.

Comment: (I know this has already been answered, but this is the answer in the form that would have helped me understand and resolve the problem quicker).

Answer (score 0):

I used plugin from

[`mhartington/nvim-typescript`](https://github.com/mhartington/nvim-typescript)

`Plug 'mhartington/nvim-typescript'`

```
set nocompatible                                                                                                
set hidden
set nowrap
set termguicolors
filetype on
map  <c-l> :tabn<cr>
map  <c-h> :tabp<cr>
map  <c-n> :tabnew<cr>
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
"typescript
Plug 'mhartington/nvim-typescript'
call plug#end()
```

Comment: None of the plugins are being installed, it just throws out the error and stops forever